# ComboCharts for more than 6 data series

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am unable to create a Combochart in VBA Excel with more than 5 data series.  Up to 5 data series, it works fine and as soon as I have 6th one, I get error: "Runtime error 1004, Parameter not valid".  As you can see it is not a lot of data, there seems to be an issue with more than 5 data series in the ComboChart. The first series is barChart (primary y-axis), rest are Scatter (all in secondary y-axis).  Please advice what may be going on here.

This is my code

```
Sub CreateComboChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngCategories As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Perf")
    

    Set rngData = ws.Range("B2:F10")
    Set rngCategories = ws.Range("B1:F1")
    
    ' Create a new chart
    Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=100, Height:=300)
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    
    ' Set the chart type to combo
    cht.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    
    ' Add data to the chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rngData
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngCategories
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ' Set the chart type for the first row (bars)
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = 8
        
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).MarkerStyle = 3
    
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(4).MarkerStyle = 8
    
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(5).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(5).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(5).MarkerStyle = 3
    ' STOPS here
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(6).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(6).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(6).MarkerStyle = 8
        
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(7).AxisGroup = 2
    cht.SeriesCollection(7).ChartType = xlXYScatter
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(7).MarkerStyle = 3
End Sub
```

This is the data

```
Plant   P1  P2  P3  P4  P5
A1  1500    7600    1300    1800    1500
A2  11.5%   12.2%   3.6%    3.3%    9.9%
A3  17.8%   19.8%   0.0%    0.0%    13.4%
A4  10.1%   10.1%   3.5%    1.4%    9.1%
A5  14.7%   15.0%   13.0%   15.1%   11.3%
A6  47.6%   55.3%   24.1%   27.2%   36.5%
A7  13.5%   11.9%   12.2%   14.0%   10.6%
A8  43.1%   40.7%   21.8%   23.6%   33.3%
```

In the above code if I change to Set rngData = ws.Range("B2:F6"), and remove seriescollection 6 and 7 I get this chart.  But does not work with "B2:F9".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue may be "plot by rows" vs "plot by columns"...

I prefer to add each series one-by-one, since it gives you more control:

```
Sub CreateComboChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, chtObj As chartObject
    Dim cht As Chart, rngData As Range
    Dim rngCategories As Range, i As Long, ms
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Perf")
    
    ws.ChartObjects(1).Delete 'remove existing plot

    Set rngData = ws.Range("B2:F10")
    Set rngCategories = ws.Range("B1:F1")
    
    ' Create a new chart
    Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=100, Height:=300)
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    
    'remove any "auto-plotted" series from the chart
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    
    'add the first series (bars)
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .XValues = rngCategories
        .Values = rngData.Rows(1)
        .AxisGroup = 1
    End With
    
    ms = 8 'marker style
    'add the rest of the series
    For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .XValues = rngCategories
            .Values = rngData.Rows(i)
            .AxisGroup = 2
            .MarkerStyle = ms
            ms = IIf(ms = 8, 3, 8) 'toggle marker style
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- The only modification required is to specify the `PlotBy` argument.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateComboChart()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim cht As Chart, i As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngCategories As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        Set rngCategories = .Rows(1)
    End With
    ' Create a new chart
    Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=100, Height:=300)
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    
    ' Set the chart type to combo
    cht.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    
    ' Add data to the chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rngData, PlotBy:=xlRows
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngCategories
    cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
    ' Set the chart type for the first row (bars)
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        cht.FullSeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 2
        cht.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlXYScatter
        cht.FullSeriesCollection(i).MarkerStyle = IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, 8, 3)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This did not work.  The code still gets stuck at the 6th dataseries. It is still a puzzle why this approach does not work.  The approach to create one-by-one as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78209491/2043446 does work.

Comment: I've upload the whole Sub and screenshot.